# People passing me on the right

Tags: driving, oregon

When turning onto my driveway from a road (when the driveway is on the left so I have to wait for an opening in the oncoming traffic lane), I often have to stop in the road for at least a few seconds, sometimes about to thirty seconds. Usually, if anyone is behind me, they pass me on the right. They go off the road to do this, and get really close to my vehicle, so it makes me really nervous. Are they doing anything illegal, and if so, would ODOT be likely to put up a "do not pass on right" sign on my request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, passing you on the shoulder is illegal, but no, the ODOT is not going to put up a sign for you to say what is already unlawful.

> [ORS 811.415](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_811.415)
> Unsafe passing on right
> penalty
>
> TEXT
> (1)A person commits the offense of unsafe passing on the right if the person:
> (a)Drives a vehicle to overtake and pass upon the right of another vehicle at any time not permitted under this section.
> (b)Drives a vehicle to overtake and pass upon the right of another vehicle at any time by driving off the paved portion of the highway.

Comment: Is there anything else I could do about this?

Comment: Not quite correct - passing on a paved shoulder is legal, it's the fact that the overtaker must "go off the road" that makes this instance illegal. From the very next section: 2a) Overtaking and passing upon the right is permitted if: (A)The overtaken vehicle is making or the driver has signaled an intention to make a left turn.